# Can I drive into Ukraine with my car?

Tags: automobiles, ukraine

I want to drive with my car to Lviv in Ukraine. Car insurance covers that, but I'm not sure if I can just drive over the border from Poland to Ukraine or if I need any special permission or documents from my car insurance company. Can't find any concrete information in the Internet.

Comment: Are you asking whether or not your insurance will cover you in Ukraine? or will it be accepted in Ukraine?

Comment: I want to know if I can just get into my car and drive over there or if somebody will stop me at the border and ask for any other documents than the passport.

Comment: Given that Russia just invaded the Ukraine is it wise to drive there at all? Yes, Donetsk is the other end of the country but avoiding even the fringes of active war zones is usually a good idea. No insurance covers airstrikes.

Comment: @Paul Wasn't much to see around the current war zone even before the invasion.

Comment: I am not seeing many foreign drivers here... but I know one thing you should definitely be aware of: after crossing the border, you have to be in the car at any time the car is on the move (as a driver or not). The car can be seized otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few that you will definitely need to carry with you.

According to the information listed in a blog [Ukraine All About U](http://ukraineallaboutu.com/blog/traveling-from-europe-to-ukraine-by-car/):

> - Car registration documents
> - Driver’s license
> - Vehicle registration plate with information written in Roman characters
> - Your country’s two-letter country code bumper sticker
> - Green Card insurance certificate

This is about the only information available online about the rules for entry to Ukraine by car.  In addition that are usual requirements by the [Border Service](http://dpsu.gov.ua/en/activities/skipping/skipping_14.htm).